# How to convert Static Google Maps to Dynamic Google Maps

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I am using python 2.7 and DJango 1.8.3, Included GMAPI module in the project for the google maps.
I have the below static google map.Just want to add the equivalent for dynamic map.

```
STATIC_URL = getattr(settings, 'GMAPI_STATIC_URL','http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap')
GEOCODE_URL = getattr(settings, 'GMAPI_GEOCODE_URL','http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode')
CHART_URL = getattr(settings, 'GMAPI_CHART_URL','http://chart.apis.google.com/chart')
```